# iOS 5 Push notification permission

Tags: ios, push-notification, push

In iOS5, when I call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes, I get the token but it does not ask for permission to the user so my app does not appear under notification center. It was asking permission under iOS4. Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When an app is installed, it won't ask for permissions again until 24 hours have passed. So simply deleting and reinstalling the app immediately won't show the pop up. Not sure if this is your scenario, but it's a possibility.

As for why the app doesn't appear in the notification center, while you also get a device token in the callback, I've got no idea. That sounds very strange indeed, and also very unlikely. Perhaps you could update your question with more information.

Comment: I restored my test device to iOS5, now it works again. It was updated from iOS4 to iOS5 directly before, it seems that can cause this kind of problems.